# Derivative of a function including Euclidean projection?

Tags: derivatives, projection

Let $C$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $z$ be a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

> Definition: Euclidean projection of $z$ onto $C$ is defined as
>   $$
> \pi_C(z)=\arg\min_{x\in C} \|z-x\|_2
> $$

Euclidean projection is not continuously differentiable so we cannot take the derivative of it at an arbitrary point. However, I am told that the following function is not as tricky as Euclidean projection:

$$
f(z) = \|z-\pi_C(z)\|^2
$$
and it is differentiable.

My questions:

1- How would you show $f(z)$ is differentiable?

2- What is the gradient of $f(z)$?

Comment: Note that $f(z) = \min_{x\in C} \|z - x\|^2$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: Could you please would that help us?

Comment: That is just a simpler expression for the function. What you need to realize here is that inside $C$, the distance is $0$, with derivative also $0$. Outside $C$, the distance change is of slope $1$ if you head straight towards $C$, so you have a discontinuity at the boundary. But by squaring, the derivative decreases to $0$ at the boundary, and the discontinuity disappears. As for showing differentiability, if you have two points in $C$ equidistant from $z$, then points on the line between them are all closer to $z$.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: Could you explain "But by squaring, the derivative decreases to 0 at the boundary, and the discontinuity disappears"?

Comment: Let $f(x)$ be the distance from $x$ to $(-\infty,0]$ on the real line. Then $$f(x) = \begin{cases}x & x> 0\\0 & x\le 0\end{cases}$$which has a discontinuous derivative. But $$g(x) = (f(x))^2 = \begin{cases}x^2 & x> 0\\0 & x\le 0\end{cases}$$ has a continuous derivative at $0$, because the parabola has $0$ derivative at $x = 0$, thus removing the discontinuity. The exact same thing happens in higher dimensions. Without the squaring, as you head directly towards $C$, the distance changes linearly, and you have that discontinuity when you reach $C$. But squaring smoothes it out.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair: Thank you so much for your intuitive example. Could you prove my question or give me a reference where I can find that?